# How to Call Remote Method service?

Tags: android, android-service, google-places-api, weather, android-service-binding

I'm developing in app, in which user can add weather card to know city weather. I'm able to populate cities with Google Places Autocomplete API & also can able to retrieve weather of selected city.

But my problem is as weather data is not fixed, it changes over time. So how can I update weather data in background once user creates that weather card. I need to do updates in background, I think I've to use android service but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will only guide you here,Nobody will provide you full code neither i will recommend anybody to do so, It is for your own good. You need to practice and explore the android programming world. So, here is my guidelines for you.

[FirebaseJobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) will fix you problem here. Before moving towards the FirebaseJobDispatcher you need to create a service class. For Services in android you should check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) out.

Lets Talk about your `service` class. 
Lets say it is `FetchWeatherData` class FetchWeatherData will extend to `IntentService` and will implement some methods. Inside `onCreate` you will write logic for fetching data from the server. Once you get the data from server you will store into the [Database](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/). Before storing into database you should check if database have the any record in it? If it does then delete it and store the new records in it.

Lets Talk about your `Activity`. Lets say it is `ShowWeatherActivity`. You will check first if you have any record in your database if there is no record then you will use `FetchWeatherData` to download weather data. Then show it.

Answer to your question can be very lengthy but i tried to explain as much which can help you get the idea of sync flow. Ofcourse your problem won't solve by reading this answer only. You need to go through these concepts

1. [Services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) (Runs on main Thread)
2. Intent-Services (Runs in background)
3. [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) (For storing data)

I have added the helpful links in answer. Follow them. I hope this will help you somewhat.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zeeshan for such detailed answer. I'll let you know how think works for me. Can't thank you euff

Comment: @KiranKoravi no problem, If this helps please mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I've created service for fetching data from server and finally storing it in database. But I've used only Service. Not a FirebaseJobDispatcher?  My Data get refreshed only when activity being loaded again. It is possible to refresh data without loading activity like cribuzz cricket live score card?

Comment: Yes you can do that. You will have to use `TimerTask` look into `timertasks`